# Trouble importing tab separated values table with read_tsv

Tags: r, csv, readr

I know this question has been asked before but I have tried many of the other solutions to no avail. I run an instrument that exports files as tab separated .csv files (I know that the file extension doesn't make a ton of sense) and I want to import them into R for processing. When I try and read the files in using read_tsv, using the code:

```
x=read_tsv('TEST.CSV', col_names = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_double(),
  X2 = col_logical()
)
Warning: 7770 parsing failures.
row col               expected    actual       file
  1  X1 no trailing characters           'TEST.CSV'
  1  X2 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE               'TEST.CSV'
  2  X1 a double                         'TEST.CSV'
  2  -- 2 columns              1 columns 'TEST.CSV'
  3  X1 a double                         'TEST.CSV'
... ... ...................... ......... ..........
See problems(...) for more details.
```

Both columns should be doubles and there should only be 1942 elements in each column. I've tried changing the encoding format with no luck. I've also tried changing the separator to a comma but that also didn't improve things. I'm not sure if there is a way for me to share the .csv file to provide more of an idea of what's going on.

When I run

```
readLines("TEST.CSV", n=5)
```

I get the following output:

```
[1] "ÿþ0" ""    ""    ""    ""   
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("TEST.CSV", n = 5) :
  line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
2: In readLines("TEST.CSV", n = 5) :
  line 2 appears to contain an embedded nul
3: In readLines("TEST.CSV", n = 5) :
  line 3 appears to contain an embedded nul
4: In readLines("TEST.CSV", n = 5) :
  line 4 appears to contain an embedded nul
5: In readLines("TEST.CSV", n = 5) :
  line 5 appears to contain an embedded nul
```

Here are photos of what the dataset looks like when opened with Excel and with Notepad
[image: Image of dataset opened in Excel]
[image: Image of dataset opened in Notepad]

I appreciate any guidance you can provide. 
Cheers!

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us the first 5 lines of TEST.CSV ?

Comment: Often, the best approach is to read in everything as character, then use `as.logical` and `as.numeric` to show you where you've gone wrong.  What is `problems(...)` showing you?

Comment: Try `readLines("TEST.CSV", n=5)` and paste the output into your query. This will just read the first 5 lines of the file without parsing or converting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Howdy~ The trick to this was that the file opens with a non-readable character of some type like maybe a carriage return. The evidence comes from the readLines output, which doesn't show what you were expecting from the file as it's opened in rich-text format editors. You just need to remove the hidden special characters and then you're good to read the file in normally. Just posting for the sake of completeness.